# How to COMPLETELY reset a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run `sp_spaceused dummybizo` I get the following results:

```
name        rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
dummybizo   0       72 KB       8 KB    8 KB        56 KB
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
name        rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
dummybizo   0       0 KB        0 KB    0 KB        0 KB
```

What is causing the reserved memory?

I have already tried to force a ghost record clean up with `alter table dummybizo rebuild;` but it doesn't change the results. I've also tried `truncate table dummybizo` but it doesn't do anything to these stats. I also note that `select * from dummybizo with (nolock)` doesn't reveal any hidden records.

What should I try next? I would like to set up the table such that the stats read

```
0   0 KB   0 KB   0 KB   0 KB
```

Comment: `DROP` then `CREATE` the table again, is this not an option?

Comment: @Mazhar it is, but I'm trying to work out how to drop and recreate the table without manually typing out all the fields

Comment: hope this helps 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9142/125287

Comment: Why manually? Don't you have the DDL in source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- TRUNCATE TABLE removes all rows from a table, but the table structure
  and its columns, constraints, indexes, and so on remain. To remove
  the table definition in addition to its data, use the DROP TABLE
  statement.
- So you need basically drop and recreation of table

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)